# Bootstrapp not working on tablet (Acer B3-A30)

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-modal

Good afternoon all,

Bought an old tablet for a demo of an app.

It looks like bootstrap is not working on some elements such modals, tabs. (its working fine on laptop and mobile). The tablet is from 2016.

Not sure what information to give at this stage, so feel free to ask any question.

Any pointers on how to fix this?

## EDIT

Browser Used - Chrome

Does it work with the same browser on another device - Yes

Bootstrap version used - 5.

Bootstrap 4 seem to work on the tablet, ideally if we could find a way to make the tablet compatible with Bootstrap 5 it would be a lot better.

MRE

```
<head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">        <title>My Procurement | {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>

</head>
<body>
…
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
…
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    </body>
</body>
```

Comment: Which browser do you use? Does it work with the same browser on another device? Also please try to extract a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - for example, single HTML page with bootstrap from `<script>` tag and not working component.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have added more detail to my original post. We noticed bootstrap 4 was working fine. So it might be a question of compatibility of bootstrap 5 with the old tablet. It would be ideal if we could make the tablet work on bootstrap 5.